# How can tkinter open with file directory of specific folder (also containing .py script) on any system?

Tags: python, tkinter

In other words if I pass off the folder to someone containing a .txt and .py, and the script is run on their machine from this folder, how can I ensure the file dialog will open with this folder to select the .txt without knowing the absolute path? Referring to `initialdir=`??

```
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.withdraw()
root.filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir='/python', title="Select file",
                                           filetypes=[("Text Files", "*.txt")])
print(root.filename)
```

Answer (score 7):

You should use the `os` module and `os.getcwd()` to find the current working directory of the .py file

```
import os
from tkinter import filedialog
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()
root.filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir=os.getcwd(), title="Select file",
                                           filetypes=[("Text Files", "*.txt")])
print(root.filename)
```

I would also suggest doing `import tkinter as tk` instead as importing everything may lead to naming conflicts if you are not careful, plus it's much easier to determine that what you are referring to came from the `tkinter` module when you prefix it with `tk`